# Can consumer group remember which all topics it is subscribed to

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and I am trying to make a multiple produce subscribe functionality.
Lets say there are N number of producers called P1,P2,P3... and M number of consumers C1,C2,C3

Now C1 need to subscribe to P1,P2 and at some point of time he needs to subscribe to P3 also. Hence C1 has a dynamic list of topics it needs to subscribe to.

I was hoping this can be achieved using high level consumer  , where we can name out consumer group and Kafka will store the offset till we read. But then what i noticed is that , we also need to give the topic names while creating high level consumer. In my case I have like 1000 number of topics i need to subscribe and this list is dynamically updated.

Is there a way , where in kafka high level consumer can remember the topics it have subscribed to and listen to them when brought up , rather than we providing the names of all the topics it was subscribed in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Kafka architecture that you outlined would work. The main issue, given that Kafka topic is a point of asynchrony between producers and consumers, is that you cannot do a clean cut switch with your "dynamic list of topics you need to subscribe to" (as you put it), since some amount of messages will presumably always be in "the queue".

Besides that, it's not exactly trivial to dynamically change the topic (and partition) in consumer clients. AFAIK Kafka is not meant to be used this way.

A better option would be to use a special message field that would tell your consumer clients whether the message is for them or not.
So you can use dedicated topics for messages that don't require this dynamic nature (in order to avoid doing this check for all messages, if possible) and a separate topic where you'd mix all messages that do require it.